# Standard Output was not what was expected in REVEL

Tags: java, revel

I'm frustrated with this error I'm getting on my assignment.  The code I have is clearly correct and running, but I'm still getting this error that the Standard Output was not what was expected.  This is the question for that particular assignment:

(Algebra: solve quadratic equations) The two roots of a quadratic equation
ax^2 + bx + c = 0 can be obtained using the following formula:
b^2 - 4ac is called the discriminant of the quadratic equation. If it is positive, the
equation has two real roots. If it is zero, the equation has one root. If it is negative,
the equation has no real roots.
Write a program that prompts the user to enter values for a, b, and c and displays
the result based on the discriminant. If the discriminant is positive, display two
roots. If the discriminant is 0, display one root. Otherwise, display “The equation
has no real roots”.
Note that you can use Math.pow(x, 0.5) to compute 2x.

And this is my response:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise03_01 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a, b, c: ");

    double a = input.nextDouble();
    double b = input.nextDouble();
    double c = input.nextDouble();

    double discriminant = Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;



    if (discriminant > 0) {
        double r1 = -b + Math.pow(discriminant, 0.5) / (2 * a);
        double r2 = -b - Math.pow(discriminant, 0.5) / (2 * a);        
        System.out.println("The equation has two roots" + r1 + " and " + r2);
    }
    else if (discriminant == 0) {
        double r1 = -b + Math.pow(discriminant, 0.5) / (2 * a);            
        System.out.println("The equation has one root " + r1);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The equation has no real roots ");
    }
}
}
```

Can you explain what "standard output was not what was expected" means? I this resolved as soon as possible because this assignment is due this saturday.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/CheckExercise/faces/CheckExercise.xhtml

Comment: On the site i commented above, it works perfectly, so i don't understand why this error keeps showing up.

Comment: Check for decimal precisions required to match the test cases.
Check for the correctly displayed sentence(Alphabetically) to match the output. What do you mean by these?

Answer (score 0):

I two faced such issues while submitting my assignments online. Most basic cause for which your answer was not accepted by system could be one of these :

- Check for whether you need to use print or println to satisfy the conditions.
- Check for decimal precisions required to match the test cases.
- Check for the correctly displayed sentence(Alphabetically) to match the output.

Let us know if you found it helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by the decimal precisions and correctly displayed sentence?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Chapter 3 Programing project 4

Comment: Well in your answer there might be output values in decimal(eg : 2.089) but expected can be decimal with two point precision(eg : 2.08).
Also expected output can be "ABC" and you are giving "ABc".
Which can cause unexpected failure.

Comment: I'm doing your advice but I'm still running into the same problems on multiple questions

Comment: I think your code is buggy. Just try with inputs : A : 0, B : 6, C : 3. Check the output and let me know if you are expecting this or else fix this.